# not getting response to the html view page

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am calling an api of node js in angular js ui-router but my $scope function didn't get the response to the html view page.

```
.state('statetwo', {
            url: '/statetwo',
            templateUrl: appHelper.templatePath('tables/basic')

        })
```

here is my controller

```
app.controller('formController', function ($scope,$http) {


    $scope.alldata=function(form)
    {
        let dataObj=JSON.stringify(form);
        alert(dataObj);



        $http.post("http://localhost:4000/login",dataObj)
            .then(function (response) {
            $scope.getdata2=response.data;
            console.log($scope.getdata2);
            //  let dataObj1=JSON.stringify($scope.getdata);
            //  $scope.data=dataObj1;
            //    console.log(dataObj1);
            })

        }
});
```

and here is my html view in html page

```
<p>{{getdata2.Result}}</p>
```

Comment: What do you mean 'didn't get the response to the html view page' ? Can you see logs in your console? o_0 Can you show us your response headers from the api endpoint?

Comment: yeah all logs are show but $scope doesn't send any response in html view

Comment: Object
FaultResponse
:
FaultCode
:
"400"
FaultString
:
"Account is not defined"
__proto__
:
Object
Result
:
"ERROR"
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: here is the api response 

{Result: "OK", UserAccountID: 0, UserAuthName: "921111", UserPassword: "Abc12345", UserDomain: "176.31.12.1", …}
Result
:
"OK"
UserAccountID
:
0
UserAuthName
:
"921111"
UserDomain
:
"176.31.12.1"
UserPassword
:
"Abc12345"
UserPort
:
"8891"
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: em, I'll try to guess: `$scope.getdata2=JSON.stringify(response);` ?

Comment: Also, start with `console.log(response);`, it will show you full response, so you can figure out what is wrong.

Comment: api data is ok and response is also ok but am trying to get response data in html page $scope is now working i think

Comment: I don't see where you're controller is being mapped to your state, it's not in the state definition nor in the template.  When you go to /state2 does your controller get called?

Comment: am just define the controller name like ng-controller="foemController" and ng-app="myApp" just define the controller like that

Answer (score 0):

Your function should look like this:

```
    $http.post("http://localhost:4000/login",dataObj)
     .then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log('successCallback');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        $scope.getdata2=JSON.stringify(response.data);
     }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log('errorCallback');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        $scope.getdata2='ERROR';
     });
```

Beacuse, you need both callback to catch 400 response from your api.

And in your html:

```
<p>{{getdata2}}</p>
```

Comment: no problem in the response of the api just problem is that when i console ($scope.getdata2) the result is ok and when i rendered the detdata2 in html the {{getdata2}} have no blank response

Comment: how can i rendered the getdata2 in my html page

Comment: Angular does this for you :) Check the JSBin https://jsbin.com/qutezah/edit?html,js,console,output . This is really hard to guess. Is templateUrl correct and working ?

Comment: Of course, in my example the JSBin sends request to `http://localhost:4000/login` and displays a string in the page, what response did you expect? Check the JSBin url again.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no problem in the response, try adding **$scope.$apply()**.

whenever there is a task that takes some amount of time, some times will need to call Angular to forcefully get your bindings to update.

If there is a problem in the response, you can see it in the console.

```
$http.post("http://localhost:4000/login",dataObj)
     .then(function (response) {
        $scope.getdata2=response.data;
        $scope.$apply();
     }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
     });
}
```